# Mac crashed after changing disk permission

Tags: macos, crash

I'm facing a problem with my Mac Mini with Mountain Lion.

When I changed my disk permission of `Macintosh` for everyone to `no access` my Mac crashed and and it's not restarting when I boot the Mac. It just stops after showing the Apple logo.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm tempted to say: "What did you expect?" Why did you try and change that? It's never wise to manually change the permission of system files/folders. See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you just selected Macintosh HD and changed "everyone" to "No Access" and did not select "Apply to enclosed items", try to:

1. Start up in single user mode by holding command-S on startup.
2. Run `mount -uw /`. `fsck -fy` is not necessarily needed.
3. Run `chmod 755 /`.
4. Run `reboot`.

If that doesn't work, try to [reinstall OS X from the recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10763). It installs a new copy of OS X over the current installation while keeping user files and settings in place. It solved a problem I had where my Mac got stuck during the startup process. If nothing else works, try to [erase and reinstall OS X](http://support.apple.com/kb/ph11273), or erase the Macintosh HD partition (not the whole drive) from Disk Utility and then choose Reinstall OS X.

If you don't already have backups, try to [save a disk image to an an external drive in Disk Utility](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1553) on the recovery partition or [copy files to an external drive in single user mode](https://superuser.com/questions/176361/mount-external-usb-drive-in-single-user-mode).

Answer (score 1):

Try booting with the <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd> (aka. <kbd>⌥ Opt</kbd>) key down. You should see one or two disk(s) visible, one of them being the `Recovery Partition`. Select it, your computer should boot (but not on your usual desktop).

From there, select `Disk Utilities` and try repairing permissions on your main disk. Try rebooting normally then, it should work.

If it's not enough, you should reboot on the recovery partition again and reinstall Mac OS X on your main disk (it won't erase your data; only the system).

Comment: the DISK Utilities showing that I cant repair the permission and the mac not detecting the Ethernet also

Comment: The try reinstalling the system :) Don't forget passing all the updates once the system is reinstalled.